# ASP.NET CSHTML Populating a Gridview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am hitting a wall with populating a `Gridview` in `ASP.NET` CSHTML.

On Page Load, I have this code to initiate data fill.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Orisoftds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection appCon = new SqlConnection(appdb))
            {

                SqlDataAdapter orisoftAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(fillist, appCon);
                orisoftAdapter.Fill(Orisoftds, "Staff_List");
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = Orisoftds.Tables["Staff_List"];
        }
```

With this , the `GridView1` will now have a `DataSource`

On my web page I have these three controls :

[image]

In this project , user will have to fill in their ID on the Text box and by clicking the submit button, the `GridView` will be filled in.

On the submit button, I have these code :

```
protected void EmpIDSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string eID = empIDTextBox.Text;

            ((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "EMPLOYEE_ID = " + eID;

        }
```

Am I missing anything as at the moment when I enter an ID to the textbox, the page will instead just do thing or seems like it refreshed doing nothing.

Is there a difference between filling a `Gridview` in `WinForms` and `HTML`?

Result should contain gridview showing only the user's profile filtered based on their ID given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Missing `GridView1.Databind()` for DataBind with Gridview,

Please use this line after:

```
GridView1.DataSource = Orisoftds.Tables["Staff_List"];
```

Comment: That actually works , but i will explain in answer.

1 question though , how come in WinForms i do not need to add databind but in HTML i have to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the DataBind method. Try calling `GridView1.Databind()` in your EmpIDSubmit_Click event.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - I am missing databind.

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I had a problem where even after databind , the result did not show.

Apparently the submit button has a broken PostBackUrl configuration as i was testing another method earlier.

I deleted my button and replaced with a new one , now results are showing properly.

I no longer need to use a stored procedure method such as :

```
using (SqlConnection appCon = new SqlConnection(appdb))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", appCon))
    {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE_ID", empIDTextBox.Text);

         using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
 }
```

Thank you everyone.